# Problem in Java concatenating two spannable strings

Tags: java, android, string, concatenation, spannable

I am new in android/java development and I have the following problem.
I am trying to concatenate two spannable strings after coloring them.
The problem is that I get the first string (st1_all=st1_orig+st1_tran)
with the desired colors, but not the second one (st2_all=st2_orig+st2_tran).
Do you have any idea what's the problem?
Belwo you find the code.
Thanks

```
//strings length
int st1_orig_length  = st1_orig.length();
int st1_tran_length  = st1_tran.length();
int st1_tot_length   = st1_orig_length+st1_tran_length;

int st2_orig_length  = st2_orig.length();
int st2_tran_length  = st2_tran.length();
int st2_tot_length   = st2_orig_length+st2_tran_length;

//strings concatenation
String st1_both = st1_orig+st1_tran;
String st2_both = st2_orig+st2_tran;

//spannable characteristics, i.e. colors
ForegroundColorSpan fcsRed   = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
ForegroundColorSpan fcsGreen = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN);

SpannableString st1_all = new SpannableString(st1_both);
SpannableString st2_all = new SpannableString(st2_both);
st1_all.setSpan(fcsRed  , 0, st1_orig_length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
st1_all.setSpan(fcsGreen, st1_orig_length, st1_tot_length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
st2_all.setSpan(fcsRed  , 0 , st2_orig_length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
st2_all.setSpan(fcsGreen, st2_orig_length, st2_tot_length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

//final text
//CharSequence st_all = TextUtils.concat(st1_all,st2_all,st1_all);
myText.setText(TextUtils.concat(st1_all,st2_all));
```